# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when container.deployVerticle is called in Verticle

Tags: java, classloader, classnotfoundexception, vert.x

I am a newbie regarding Vertx, so this might be a simple question. 
When i try to run a verticle from commandline i allways get a ClassNotFoundException when i try to programatically deploy another verticle :

container.deployVerticle("melby.poc.verticles.AuditVerticle");
AuditVerticle is itself a verticle, and is located in a sub package from the main" verticle that i try to run

I have also tried to run this as a module as well without any luck
command i use to run the verticle is :
vertx run src\main\java\melby\poc\Server.java

Consolle output when i try to start the verticle is :

```
Succeeded in deploying verticle
Exception in Java verticle
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: melby.poc.verticles.AuditVerticle
        at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.ModuleClassLoader.loadFromModule(ModuleC
lassLoader.java:127)
        at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassL
oader.java:108)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.java.JavaVerticleFactory.createVerticle(
JavaVerticleFactory.java:55)
        at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$21.run(DefaultPla
tformManager.java:1748)
        at org.vertx.java.core.impl.DefaultContext$3.run(DefaultContext.java:175
)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(Single
ThreadEventExecutor.java:370)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThread
EventExecutor.java:116)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I use vertx 2.1.5 and java 8
Do i somehow need to change/add the classpath for vertx so it is able to load the classes in the same source folder ?

**Update :** 
*I was able to make it work by adding a mod.json file defining the runnable verticle and adding this file to the root catalog.
From this catalog i am now able to run the command :
vertx run src\main\java\melby\poc\Server.java -cp target/classes
I still dont anderstand why I need a mod.json file and why i need to define -cp
If i dont programatically deploy verticles i dont need this.*

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.reactiverse</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.28</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>vmp</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>initialize</goal>
          <goal>package</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <redeploy>true</redeploy>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

add the above plugin to your pom.xml file within  that worked for me